# Diplôme en France when renewing titre de séjour?

Tags: france, us-citizens, residence-cards

I have been living in France for three years (at first on a work visa) with my wife who is a French national.

I recently had a rendez-vous at my local préfecture to renew my existing titre de séjour "vie privée et familiale" which I received last year.

Everything went fine at the rendez-vous and they gave me a receipt, but now I've received a letter asking for two things, one of which is unreasonable (what else is new?) but the other completely bizarre and unexpected:

> Afin de compléter votre demande de titre de séjour, je vous invite à envoyer au plus vite les documents énumérés ci-dessous :
>
> - Acte de mariage de moins de 3 mois
> - Diplôme en France

They want a response "dans un délai de 7 jours" and who knows what that means. The letter is dated 22 fev. and I didn't see it until today, the 28th (it's postmarked the 25th).

First of all I gave them an acte de mariage but apparently they want a more recent copy? How could I possibly obtain that so quickly? I went ahead and ordered a new copie intégrale, but that will obviously take a few weeks to arrive.

More importantly however is the completely bizarre request for a "diplôme en France". Is there some meaning to that I'm missing besides just "French diploma?" Obviously I do not have such a thing. Nor have I ever been asked for that, nor obviously is it mentioned in the [relevant list of documents](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2209). I almost wonder if it could be a mistake. There is no reason for them to believe I have a French diploma, nor should it be relevant for vie privée et familiale. Has anyone else seen this before?

Comment: Would you mind posting a picture of the letter (blacking out any personal info)? Might clarify a few things. The préfecture asking for documents you already submittted is not unheard of. But asking for a diploma if it is clear that you never had one is always a bit...weird...but no longer surprises me.

Comment: In my post I included the relevant part of the letter as it was written, verbatim. The rest was just boilerplate. I have no idea how to even begin responding.

Comment: Well I requested for a copy of the letter because of two things: 1) sometimes they put things in there that might seem boilerplate but it gives clues as to why they ask for certain docs; 2) you also forgot to mention in which prefecture you belong to. This will help me provode you with a better answer. If not I can only base my answers on what you write. It's not unheard of that prefectures lose your docs and that's why they are asking for new ones. At this point, what I can suggest is to write back, sending the new copy of the acte de mariage and explaining why you don't have a diploma.